# VBA remove carriage returns from notepad file

Tags: vba, notepad

I have a notepad file that contains numbers on separate lines

```
   10345872

   96625115
   96699612
   10305012

   10202214
   10609010

   10299680
   96688192

   10302010
```

I need to loop through the file deleting the spaces in between (they are not actually spaces, they are carriage returns) but not moving the numbers to one continuous line (they must each be on a separate line).
Can anyone help?

Comment: The lazy way is to repeat `replace(s, vbnewline & vbnewline, vbnewline)` until it stops changing.

Comment: If I could read the values into an Array and remove the empty values and then reDim the array it would work. I could then re-write the array to the text file.

Comment: You could do that too with `split(s, vbnewline)`.